# Setting up maven resources when testing

Tags: maven-2, resources, classpath

I need resource goal of resource plugin to be set up differently for
test phase, than for build phase. When testing I need to exclude stuff
from src/main/resources. It seems it can't be done, testResources goal
is irrelevant for what I need and resource goal can have only one
setting in pom definition, that takes effect in both test and build
phase...

For example, I'd need following settings to look differently (some
excludes) in testing phase :

```
           <resources>
             <resource>
               <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
               <includes>
                   <include>**/*.java</include>
                   <include>service.properties</include>
               </includes>
             </resource>
             <resource>
               <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
               <includes>
                   <include>**/*.xml</include>
                   <include>**/*.properties</include>
               </includes>
             </resource>
           </resources>
```

The ideal behavior would be if I could define "src/main/*" in
`<testResources>` but it unfortunately can't be done right now

Please help, I'd have to do tons of code modification if I didn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to have the resources as a separate project that is not included at test time, which is a mess.

I can imagine why you would want to do this, but you aren't really testing the artifact at that point.

This is where IoC really shines.  Your components get their resources injected instead of the component having to have runtime selection code of which resource (test or actual) that should be chosen.  This is important because the test code can't test the code that chooses the test.  If you see what I mean :-)

If you are using Spring, you can create a test-context.xml containing bean overrides for the changes you want to make, then load that after loading all your other contexts.  When it is loaded, you will get a warning that the beans are being overridden, look at them closely the first time to be sure the test bean is overriding the production bean.  Then that bean should be injected as you expect.

Comment: The reason I want to do it is actually due to 2 spring contexts (app / test) - spring bean definitions that have same names in classes and test-classes .... Instead of changing code, I'd rather do something like this...Otherwise there naming conflicts

Comment: I edited the above for what happens in Spring.  This is a very very common case and doesn't require changing the compilation or generating multiple artifacts.  Let me know if you have further questions and I can update more.

Comment: Hey Brian, thank you, but it's way too much complicated. There are 700 beans on project classpath, hundreds of beans in one of its dependencies + testing context from those beans...Overriding beans is absolutely not enough, I really need an answer for this question, not a workaround

Comment: It's a huge project...hundreds of tables

Comment: I think I'll have to create my own maven mojo in addition to testResources and resources mojo... It was the first think that came to my mind, but it seemed complicated to me... Now I have to do it anyway

Comment: For most people, this is the way it's done, not a workaround.  :-)  So you might ask if there's a better way to structure your code to avoid this problem altogether.  With 700+ beans, I'd consider subclassing org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner to transform the Spring context when it is loaded, then you don't have to maintain separate contexts that need to be kept in sync.  At least I would do that before I created a mojo, kind of a last resort for me...  good luck!